# Docker multi-stage build: COPY --from=builder failed: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, docker, dockerfile

The following Dockerfile

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-devel-ubuntu18.04 AS builder

...

RUN ls $HOME/bin

FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-runtime-ubuntu18.04

COPY --from=builder $HOME/bin/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

returns

```sh
Step 21/23 : RUN ls $HOME/bin
 ---> Running in a8dee059d9a6
ffmpeg

Removing intermediate container a8dee059d9a6
 ---> 1cb71814a43b

Step 22/23 : FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-runtime-ubuntu18.04
 ---> e442a6c5cd9a

Step 23/23 : COPY --from=builder $HOME/bin/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b9283a57527d878d76ea8f8a1e87eb1a6466e849ee1cb4bc69601e184f6dea1f/merged/bin/ffmpeg: no such file or directory
```

Am I missing something? Is it a bug in docker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `$HOME` (or any environment variable) in the `COPY` operation. You have details in this issue https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34482

Simple test:

This works:

```
FROM ubuntu AS builder

RUN echo "fooo" > ${HOME}/test.txt

FROM ubuntu
COPY --from=builder /root/test.txt /tmp/test.txt
RUN cat /tmp/test.txt
```

This doesn't work, same error as yours:

```
FROM ubuntu AS builder

RUN echo "fooo" > ${HOME}/test.txt

FROM ubuntu
COPY --from=builder ${HOME}/test.txt /tmp/test.txt
RUN cat /tmp/test.txt
```

Comment: The `$HOME` variable is most likely defined by the shell, which you have in the `RUN` command, but not in the `COPY` command which is expanded by docker itself. One would need to set it with an `ENV` step for the `COPY` command to work.

Comment: @yzT @BMitch It worked like a charm with `/root` instead of `$HOME`. Thanks!